# How to compute some basic statistics in R with the density and support only?

Tags: r, statistics, probability, distribution

I have no sample and I'd like to compute the variance, mean, median, and mode of a distribution which I only have a vector with it's density and a vector with it's support. Is there an easy way to compute this statistics in R with this information?

Suppose that I only have the following information:

```
Support
Density
sum(Density) == 1 #TRUE
length(Support)==length(Density)# TRUE
```

Comment: does your "support" vector acts as a x axis for the density one? In other words, if you plot   x=support, y=density you get the actual distribution on the right scale?

Comment: Yes that’s the way it is indeed!

Answer (score 3):

You have to do weighted summations

F.e., starting with @Johann example

```
set.seed(312345)
x = rnorm(1000, mean=10, sd=1)
x_support = density(x)$x
x_density = density(x)$y

plot(x_support, x_density)
mean(x)
```

prints

```
[1] 10.00558
```

and what, I believe, you're looking for

```
m = weighted.mean(x_support, x_density)
```

computes mean as weighted mean of values, producing output

```
10.0055796130192
```

There are `weighted.sd`, `weighted.sum` functions which should help you with other quantities you're looking for.

Plot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a mathematical solution, and an empirical one is all right, you can achieve a pretty good approximation by sampling.

Let's generate some data:

```
set.seed(6854684)
x = rnorm(50,mean=10,sd=1)
x_support = density(x)$x
x_density = density(x)$y
# see our example:
plot(x_support, x_density )
# the real mean of x
mean(x)
```

Now to 'reverse' the process we generate a large sample from that density distribution:

```
x_sampled = sample(x = x_support, 1000000, replace = T, prob = x_density)
# get the statistics
mean(x_sampled)
median(x_sampled)
var(x_sampled)
etc...
```

Comment: The thing here is that I need the exact values of everything.

Comment: Just increase 1000000 to a larger number until you get required precision! (Just joking, I wouldn't know how to solve it analytically)

Comment: I doubt that exact values are not possible unless the distribution is discrete.